# Formal Statistical Test Equivalent to Comparing Box Plots

Tags: categorical-data, boxplot

I have a data set consisting of a continuous feature compared to a discrete, categorical feature. Currently, I have generated a stacked box plot for each dependent category comparing the values of independent variable (I have included an image of said chart below). What would be a formal statistical test (if any) equivalent to eyeballing the box plots and drawing conclusions from their shape like "samples with a higher independent variable are more often categorized in group 2 than the other groups." Alternatively is their a test for statistical significance that is based on the spread of data?

[image]

**EDIT**

The data is the results of an experiment where people were asked to choose one of three unique ice cream flavors and the time they took to make their decision was recorded (recorded to the nearest one thousandth of a second). I am trying to relate the time it took them to make their decision and the decision they chose. The top box plot is a representation of the entire data set, while the subsequent three plots are for the three available choices: A, B and C in that order. One can see that the flavor A was the least popular (the density of data points on the graph is the lightest). It also took longer for people to choose that flavor. This trend is explainable qualitatively as flavor A was the most ridiculous, but I am not exactly sure how one could statistically prove this assertion based on the data.

Comment: Both features look discrete in this graphic.  Which one do you take to be continuous?

Comment: @whuber The data is continuous its just that the majority of the data is concentrated at specific intervals, theoretically, it is continuous and there exists a minority of data between these bands

Comment: The problem, though, is that data with ties--and these certainly look like ties--simply aren't continuous and this matters because the possibility of ties changes the interpretation. The chief example is that three of the four quartiles are at the extreme left, showing that at least one-quarter of all the values in those three groups are the same.  A better description of these data would therefore be helpful.

Comment: I added a description of the data. If the participant chose a flavor before the tester could even finish posing the question, a value of 0 was assigned for their decision time, and the majority of individuals choosing flavors B and C decided instantaneously, hence the box plot shape. The maximum value is 10 seconds, which is the longest we gave someone to make their decision. I contribute the ties to human error (I did not conduct the experiment and I assume that their timing apparatus favored these values)

Comment: I could believe the data are recorded to the nearest tenth of a second, but not to a thousandth of a second--people don't react that quickly or consistently. And I cannot believe even that, due to the very large numbers of points at just three values in the right half of the graph.  Presumably the very right is the limit of ten seconds, which needs to be treated as *right censored.*